# Overriding 2 functions in vendor package class

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm currently trying to retrieve the SMTP Queue-ID when using the Laravel (5.6) `Mail` class.

I have copied the file [`vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php) to `/app/OverriddenAbstractSmtpTransport.php` and made an `alias` in `config/app.php`, made my changes:

1: 
on [line#395](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php#L395) I added `return` in front of the line, so we obtain the output

2:
[line#492](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php#L492) replaced with `$message->queue_ids[] = $this->streamMessage($message);`

So I can access `queue_ids` from the `message` property in the `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent`-event

Now this works, but I don't think it's a very safe approach to modifying the vendor class, as it might cause a breaking change when running security updates.

Is there a simpler/better/safer solution to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying the whole class is **risky** - if any updates are done to the vendor class in a newer version, they'll never make it into your copy. A **safer** way is to extend the original class and overwrite those 2 functions. There is still a **risk** of some changes being done to those functions in vendor class, but it's much lower now. Another option would be to extend the original class and add new methods - they will have access to all public and protected properties/methods of the original class and that could be enough to get you what you need.

Whatever version you choose, you'll need to later register the new class as a new driver/transport for Swift. Check the following snippet for an example: https://gist.github.com/maxwellimpact/46ded5c553f68946d13d

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve it by just extending and overriding a single function, using the example snippet! 